# 17 of Tammuz occurrences

Tags: history, fast-days

What happened on the  17 of Tammuz to inspire the fast observed on that day?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Moshe Rabbeinu broke the luchos when he came down from Har Sinai and saw the eigel
2. The karbon tamid was no longer brought in the first Bais Hamikdosh.
3. The destruction of the second Bais Hamikdosh started.
4. Apostumos burnt the Torah
5. A tzelem was placed in the heichal

Source: Mishna Ta'anis [4:6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%93_%D7%95)